# Prove that Tr(B) is rank(B) if B is any 2x2 matrix such that $B^2 = B$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

How do I prove this? I proved in the last part that Tr(B) was an integer, but I'm lost on how to prove this fact.

I'm guessing the first step would be to put B in rref form, but I'm not sure how I'd go from there

Where Tr() is trace and rank() is the rank.

Comment: Row reduction is likely to destroy the property that $B^2=B$.

Comment: Unsure of what level you are at. What is your definition of "rank"? What do you know about "rank" other than its definition? Like, do you know that if $B$ is full rank and $B\vec{v}=\vec{0}$, that this implies $\vec{v}=\vec{0}$? Do you know that if $B$ only has rank $1$ that there is a nonzero $\vec{v}$ such that $B\vec{v}=\vec{0}$ and another nonzero $\vec{w}$ such that $B\vec{w}\neq\vec{0}$?

Answer (score 2):

It's not just $2
\times2$ matrices. If $B^2=B$ then $B$ is diagonalisable with eigenvalues
either $0$ or $1$. The multiplicity of $1$ as an eigenvalue is the rank of $B$.

Comment: We haven't learned about eigenvalues yet so they want us to do it in a simpler way I'm guessing.

Comment: Another way to say Lord sharks answer is that B must fix its output space.  For any x in the image, there is a y (by defn) such that By=x. So Bx = B^2 y = By = x. Matrix in this basis defined by image is just the identity on this subspace and so trace is the rank

Comment: Note: trace is basis indepdent: Tr(P^-1 A P) = trA.

Comment: Note 2: the kernel of B must intersect image of B only at {0}

Answer (score 0):

This is a guide, not a full answer.

---

Break it into the cases of rank 0, 1, 2. Rank 0 is pretty simple. Rank 1 is easy to do if you think about what rank means for the matrix elements (think about the two rows independently). Rank 2 is easy because it has full rank so it is invertible. Apply an inverse to your equation for $B$ and see what happens.

Comment: How would I operate on B so that it gets a rank of 0?

Comment: Don't operate on it. Assume that it has rank 0. What matrix has rank 0?

Comment: I see. Only a 0 matrix has rank 0. So, if B had rank 1, would that mean there is no K, such that K*(b11) = b21 and K*b12= b22?

Comment: Wait, take B11 = 0, B12  = 0, B21 = 1, and B22 = 2. The rank is 1, right? But the trace is 2.

Comment: @Goldname But your example doesn't satisfy $B^2=B$.

Answer (score 0):

An outline with just a few gaps you can fill in. This approach tries to only use the very basic definition of rank as the count of the number of pivot positions. No treating matrices as linear operators on vectors. It's not very elegant in this form, but it is elementary.

There are only three possibilities for the rank: $0$, $1$, or $2$.

- If the rank of $B$ is $0$, then there is a trivial reason why you can conclude its trace is $0$.
- If the rank of $B$ is $2$, then $B$ must be the identity matrix. Why? Because through row operations, $B\sim I$. And row operations are equivalent to left-multiplying by elementary matrices. So $B=E_1\cdots E_kI=E_1\cdots E_k$. But $B^2=B$ implies $(E_1\cdots E_k)(E_1\cdots E_k)=E_1\cdots E_k$. Since the elementary matrices are invertible, this means $E_1\cdots E_k=I$. So we've established $B=E_1\cdots E_k=I$. So now it's trivial why the trace must be $2$.
- If the rank of $B$ is $1$, then either $B\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&k\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=:U,$ or $B\sim\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=:V$. Similar to the rank 2 case, consider $$B=E_1\cdots E_kU\qquad\text{or}\qquad B=E_1\cdots E_kV$$ and then do this trick with $U$ and $V$, factoring each as a $2\times1$ by a $1\times2$: $$B=E_1\cdots E_k\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{or}\qquad B=E_1\cdots E_k\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
  $$B=\left(E_1\cdots E_k\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{or}\qquad B=\left(E_1\cdots E_k\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
  $$B=J\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{or}\qquad B=J\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ where $J$ is the left column of $E_1\cdots E_k$ and therefore cannot be a column of all zeros. Since $B^2=B$, you have $$J\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}J\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}=J\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{or}\qquad J\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}J\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}=J\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
  $$J^TJ\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}J\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}=J^TJ\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{or}\qquad J^TJ\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}J\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}=J^TJ\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
  $$c\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}J\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}=c\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{or}\qquad c\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}J\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}=c\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ with $c>0$ (because $J$ was not all zeroes) so you may divide by $c$ to get: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}J\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{or}\qquad \begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}J\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ There is a very similar way to act on the right side to get to: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}J=1\qquad\text{or}\qquad \begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}J=1$$ which implies $$\operatorname{tr}\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}J\right)=1\qquad\text{or}\qquad \operatorname{tr}\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}J\right)=1$$ But within the argument of trace, you may commute to get: $$\operatorname{tr}\left(J\begin{bmatrix}1&k\end{bmatrix}\right)=1\qquad\text{or}\qquad \operatorname{tr}\left(J\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}\right)=1$$ $$\operatorname{tr}(B)=1\qquad\text{or}\qquad \operatorname{tr}(B)=1$$

Comment: The rank $2$ case can be simplified: If $B$ is full rank, it is invertible, therefore you can just multiply the equation $B^2=B$ with $B^{-1}$ to obtain $B = B^2B^{-1} = BB^{-1} = I$.

Comment: @celtschk "If $B$ is full rank, it is invertible" is indeed a fact. How many lines would it take to prove that fact? It is not clear to me that the OP is at a level where they can just cite that fact. Maybe they are, but as I say in the answer's introduction, I am trying to answer based purely on the definition of rank as a count of pivot positions, and little else. The only other thing I'm using is the connection between elementary row operations and left-multiplication by elementary matrices.

Comment: Not many lines. $v\mapsto Bv$ is obviously surjective (that's what "full rank" means), so we only have to prove that it's injective. For that, assume $Bu=Bv$. Then due to linearity, $B(u-v)=0$, and since $B$ is full rank, this implies $u-v=0$, that is, $u=v$. I never heard the rank defined as count of pivot positions; for me, the definition of rank is the dimension of the image.